# How to change angular version in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a  nativescript project using Angular 9 and i want to downgrade Angular version to Version 8 as I am facing a lot issues with plugins like nativescript-google-maps-sdk.

I tried

```
npm i nativescript-angular@8.0.0 --save

./node_modules/.bin/update-app-ng-deps

./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs
```

Hare is my package.json before this

```
    {
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.regooapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "ngcc": "ngcc --properties es2015 module main --first-only",
    "postinstall": "npm run ngcc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~9.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^1.0.0",
    "kinvey-nativescript-sdk": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-mediafilepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-radial-gradient": "^0.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.24",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~9.1.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.0",
    "tns-android": "6.5.3",
    "tns-ios": "6.5.4",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "~6.5.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

and after :

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.regooapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "ngcc": "ngcc --properties es2015 module main --first-only",
    "postinstall": "npm run ngcc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~9.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^1.0.0",
    "kinvey-nativescript-sdk": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "^8.0.0",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-mediafilepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-radial-gradient": "^0.8.0",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.24",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.0",
    "tns-android": "6.5.3",
    "tns-ios": "6.5.4",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "~6.5.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

I noticed "@nativescript/angular": "~9.0.0" and I don't get why did it not change it.

when I run a tns build android I get an error :

app\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:244
throw err;

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null:

I could use some help please, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the version for `@nativescript/angular` manually and re-installing?

Comment: I did change it manually, but it says to me it can find it. I did tns build android